# Resolve an issue with scope of classes in a rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

I'm having an issue with a rails controller not being able to find a class definition because it resolves the scope incorrectly.

Specifically, in my ApplicationController:

```
require 'memcache'
$memcache = MemCache.new("localhost:11211")
```

doesn't work. I get the error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant ApplicationController::MemCache):
```

Rails thinks that the MemCache class should somehow be in the scope of the ApplicationController.

Anyone have an idea why?

Also, this is code I inherited. Is it better practice to put the memcache connection in an initializer? If so, how do I connect to it from the Controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use the memcache_client gem, which puts a rails-friendly wrapper around memcache for you.  Then you can access the memcache store as a hash called CACHE and not worry about all the connection stuff.

https://github.com/mperham/memcache-client

Although, looking at this page it looks like it's been superseded by something called 'dalli'.  Give that a go.

Comment: Thanks for this note. I looked into it and it definitely looks like an option. But I don't want to re-do all the memcache access in the app right now, I just want to get this working. 

It's been working for a while, but when I do a local install on my machine it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `MemCache` doesn't exist, you need to use`Memcached`

```
$memcached = Memcached.new 'localhost:11211'
```

Comment: This has been working for a while. Plus I can run it from the `console` and it works.

Comment: @Kevin Bedell - What gems are you using? What Rails version?